# Automatically compute and name several new versions of eachvariable in a dataset

Tags: r, function, for-loop

For many of my variables, I often need to create three new versions (i.e., mean-centered, mean-centered plus one standard deviation, and mean centered minus one standard deviation) before I can run simple effects tests.

I can create a function to calculate each new variable, but this is does not rename the variable automatically, and is time-consuming and repetitive to do for many variables.

```
# example data of test performance
d <- read.table(header=T, text='
 subject sex    math  read   sci
       1   M     7.9  12.3  10.7
       2   F     6.3  10.6  11.1
       3   F     9.5  13.1  13.8
       4   M    11.5  13.4  12.9
')

# function to create mean-centered version of variable
mc <- function(x) {
    x - mean(x, na.rm=T)
}
d$readMC <- mc(d$read)

# function to create mc version minus 1 SD
msd <- function(x) {
    x - sd(x, na.rm=T)
}
d$readMCmsd <- msd(d$read_mc)

# function to create mc version plus 1 SD
psd <- function(x) {
    x + sd(x, na.rm=T)
}
d$readMCpsd <-psd(d$read_mc)
```

For a dataset like the one above how can I write a single functions or for-loops to calculate, rename, and add to my dataset three new versions of the variables math, read and sci?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Your function could be something like

```
foo <- function(x, ...) {
    MC <- x - mean(x, ...)
    SD <- sd(MC, ...)
    data.frame(MC = MC, MCmsd = MC - SD, MCpsd = MC + SD)
}
```

And then run it on the `math`, `sci`, and `read` columns with `lapply`

```
lapply(d[-(1:2)], foo, na.rm = TRUE)
# $math
#     MC      MCmsd      MCpsd
# 1 -0.9 -3.1241103  1.3241103
# 2 -2.5 -4.7241103 -0.2758897
# 3  0.7 -1.5241103  2.9241103
# 4  2.7  0.4758897  4.9241103
# 
# $read
#      MC      MCmsd      MCpsd
# 1 -0.05 -1.3056539  1.2056539
# 2 -1.75 -3.0056539 -0.4943461
# 3  0.75 -0.5056539  2.0056539
# 4  1.05 -0.2056539  2.3056539
# 
# $sci
#       MC      MCmsd      MCpsd
# 1 -1.425 -2.8955441 0.04554412
# 2 -1.025 -2.4955441 0.44554412
# 3  1.675  0.2044559 3.14554412
# 4  0.775 -0.6955441 2.24554412
```

Comment: If the list elements in `foo` are just named `MC`, `MCmsd` etc. then the OP can do `cbind(d, apply(d[-(1:2)], 2, foo))` and all the columns will be named the way they want.

Comment: Oh yes!  Oops, didn't notice that.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you both so much this is perfect!